# Problem in creating the query containing a CROSS JOIN followed by a LEFT JOIN in Microsoft Access

Tags: sqlite, ms-access, join, group-by, cross-join

I'm trying to convert the following `SQLite` query to a `MS-ACCESS` (Microsoft Access 2016) query without any success:

query in `SQLite`:

```
SELECT c.CategoryName, s.SubCategoryName, COUNT(l.LoanDate) AS Count
FROM LoanCategories c CROSS JOIN LoanSubCategories s
LEFT JOIN Loans l
ON l.LoanCatId = c.CategoryId AND l.LoanSubCatId = s.CategoryId AND l.LoanDate = '19990125'
GROUP BY c.CategoryName, s.CategoryName;
```

I've tried the following query in `MS-ACCESS` which leads to the 'Syntax error in JOIN operation' error:

my query in `MS-ACCESS`:

```
SELECT c.CategoryName, s.SubCategoryName, COUNT(l.LoanDate) AS Count
FROM LoanCategories c, LoanSubCategories s
LEFT JOIN Loans l
ON l.LoanCatId = c.CategoryId AND l.LoanSubCatId = s.CategoryId AND l.LoanDate = '19990125'
GROUP BY c.CategoryName, s.CategoryName;
```

How could I rewrite the query in `MS-ACCESS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax in MS-Access is quite different.

The explicit `CROSS` join is not supported and you must use the old comma-syntax.

Also, the `ON` clause of a join can't contain expressions like `LoanDate = '19990125'`.

The query could be written like this:

```
SELECT t.CategoryName, t.SubCategoryName, Nz(l.Count, 0) AS Count
FROM (
  SELECT c.CategoryId, c.CategoryName, 
         s.CategoryId AS SubCategoryId, s.CategoryName AS SubCategoryName
  FROM LoanCategories AS c, LoanSubCategories AS s
) AS t
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT LoanCatId, LoanSubCatId, COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM Loans
  WHERE LoanDate = '19990125'
  GROUP BY LoanCatId, LoanSubCatId
) AS l ON l.LoanCatId = t.CategoryId AND l.LoanSubCatId = t.SubCategoryId;
```